# Интерпретация браузера

Tags: php, css, браузер

В определенный момент мне нужно вставить такой стиль `$rstyle = 'style="background: url("/bitrix/templates/bt-mebel/images/menu-right.gif") no-repeat scroll right top transparent; padding: 0 12px 0 0;"';`

Но хром показывает его таким образом:`style="background: url(" bitrix="" templates="" bt-mebel="" images="" menu-right.gif")="" no-repeat="" scroll="" right="" top="" transparent;="" padding:="" 0="" 12px="" 0;"="" class="left" 0;&quot;`

А мозила таким: `style="background: url("`

Как можно сделать чтобы он нормально работал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кавычки экранировать надо.

```
$rstyle = 'style="background: url(\'/bitrix/templates/bt-mebel/images/menu-right.gif\') no-repeat scroll right top transparent; padding: 0 12px 0 0;"';
```